# Search box for mobile websites

Tags: search, mobile, search-box

After the search box is selected, it should expand in all directions to take up the remaining top row of the page in mobile device.I want to use HTML5,CSS3 and simple Javascript(no libraries).
How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the way.Used **javascript** to move the search box up.
I passed the textbox as obj in the function below..It works!!!

```
    function findPos(obj) { 
            var curtop = 0;
                if (obj.offsetParent) {
                do {
                curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                    curtop=curtop-5;
            return [curtop];
        }
        }
```